# Standard deviation for average sentence and paragraph length?

Tags: statistics

I was able to find a source that gave an average for sentence length in the english language of 14 words. I am curious as to what the standard deviation for that number is.

Also, I couldn't find any averages for how many sentences are in a paragraph. Again, I am also interested in knowing the standard deviation for that.

I know these averages can vary highly depending on the document.

Comment: Please, can you share your source?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requests resources.

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth, I am not quite sure what you mean by "it requests resources".

Comment: The results will be found, if anywhere, in an article or collection of statistics. If found, the answer will be there in black and white. So essentially, this is a request for a link to the appropriate article etc. But requests for resources are off-topic on ELU; this would be a better fit on ELU.Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper empirically fits a distribution to the sentence lengths in a variety of English and Greek works:

> Sichel, HS. *On a Distribution Representing Sentence-Length in Written Prose.* Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (General)
>   Vol. 137, No. 1 (1974), pp. 25-34

This in turn relies on two other papers that measured average word and sentence length in the works of Thomas Babington Macaulay, HG Wells, and GK Chesterton:

> Williams, CB. *A note on the statistical analysis of sentence-length
>   as a criterion of literary style*. Biometrika (1940), **31**, 356-361.
>
> Yule, GU. *On sentence-length as a statistical characteristic of style
>   in prose: with applications to two cases of disputed authorship.*
>   Biometrika (1939), **30**, 363-390.

- Thomas Babington Macaulay: mean sentence length 22.07 words, variance
  230.22
- HG Wells: mean 24.08,  variance 199.38
- GK Chesterton: mean 25.91, variance 131.05

Comment: Have you tried more modern works? OP does not restrict the domain to even say 'fiction', and certainly not to pre-1937 works.